# Remove SOAP:body element from XML

Tags: java, xml, soap

I got a SOAP response in String which I converted to SOAP message using **MessageFactory** and got the SOAP body out of it. I converted this SOAP body to String again using **DOMSource and Transformer** because at the end I need only raw xml without SOAP tags. Now I have below xml in **String format** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ABC>
        // Some other content
    </ABC>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I have to remove **soapenv:Body** tags and get the `<ABC />` part out of it. My desired output is :

```
<ABC>
        // Some other content
    </ABC>
```

Comment: Maybe you should show your desired output as well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Edited the question.